# How to update sencha cordova version

Tags: node.js, extjs, cordova

Trying to build a sencha project with:

```
sencha app refresh
sencha app build package
```

It is usually built on another machine that's unavailable right now.

I can see one of the things that has changed is in `cordova.js`: from:

`CORDOVA_JS_BUILD_LABEL = 3.3.0` to:
`CORDOVA_JS_BUILD_LABEL = 3.0.0-0-ge670de9`

So this newer build machine is on an outdated version of cordova it appears.

So I ran `npm install cordova -g` to update it.

But it builds the same. What needs updating and how do I do this?

Answer (score 1):

With npm you update the cordova binaries, but not the existing Cordova projects. In order to update the iOS/Android/WP/... projects, go into your main cordova project folder (in your case, the cordova folder inside your Sencha app) and execute:

```
cordova platform update ios
```

Replace ios for the platform you want to update. If you have several target plaforms, run the command once for each one.

I would recommend you to update all the plugins after the upgrade. For that, run:

```
cordova plugin list
```

in the same folder as before, and do a

```
cordova plugin remove plugin_name
cordova plugin add plugin_name
```

for each plugin that you are currently using.